# icinga web 2 dashboard showing specific servicegroups

Tags: dashboard, icinga

I've succesfully set up my icinga2 services and addded them to two several ServiceGroups inside the same host.
Is it possible to create an icinga2web dashboard showing only those serviegroups (inside the same host) which contain at least a service with a critical state?

Thus far I can only get a list of all servicegroups inside the host *test* sorted by severity:

*/icinga-web2/monitoring/list/servicegroups?host=test&sort=services_severity*

Seems that the list of ServiceGroups is not capable of accessing service states or using filters in any way :S

Don't even know where to look in the icinga2 documentation concerning dashboarding in icinga web 2. Help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

You can customize your dashboard,
goto

```
Dashboard>Add Dashlet
```

click `Dashboard` in right-side tabs one `v` symbol is there, on mouse hover you will get that **Add Dashlet** option!

Enter url like

```
monitoring/list/servicegrid
```

Dashlet Title

```
As your wish
```

And click **Add to Dashboard** button, now you got all services with some box, it will show all services!!